# Why does shell interpret my "find" command differently in-line than by executed script?

Tags: shell, sh

I'm working on a deployment script written in shell to be executed on a Linux server. Part of the requirements is that some of the folders on the source-side get aggregated in a single folder on the target-side. These will not change for the history of the project, so for them I have created an associative array as follows:

```
declare -A DIRSET
DIRSET["Content_A"]='/contents'
DIRSET["Content_B"]='/contents'
DIRSET["Templates"]='/templates'
DIRSET["Other Content"]='/templates'
```

This associative array is used to map the source directories to the target directory. Later in my script, I loop through these using a loop similar to this:

```
for key in "${!DIRSET[@]}"
do
    SUBDIR=${DIRSET[$key]}
    find . -type d -name "'$key'" | while read line; do
        if ls -1qA "${line}/" | grep -q
        then
        # to strip away './'
        OLDDIR=${line:2:${#line}}
        SUBPATH="${PROJ_ROOT}/AggregateFolder/${SUBDIR}"
        rsync -rvic -e "ssh some/.ssh/dir" "${OLDDIR}/" "${SUBPATH}"
        fi
done
```

This loop finds the directories to be aggregated using "find" and then feeds them into an "rsync" command. Somehow the contents from "Templates" make it over, whereas the contents from "Other Content" don't. It seems that the "find" command isn't returning any results even though the directory exists.

What's strange is that when I open my shell, declare the variables in-line, and perform the same "find" as in the loop segment above, I get results. I've tried removing the single quotes from around "key" and putting them around the associative array key definitions like below:

```
DIRSET["'Other Content'"]='/templates'
...
find . -type d -name "$key"
```

But this also produces no results from the "find". I put the command in a echo in the script to ensure that the variable was getting passed into the command as expected:

```
echo "find . -type d -name $key"
find . -type d -name "$key"
```

But the output ends up like this where none of the find commands in the loop work:

```
...
find . -type d -name Templates
find . -type d -name 'Other Content'
```

Note, if I don't have single quotes around either the associative array key or its "$key" reference,  I get an error where shell is attempting to interpret my string as a series of space-separated commands.

Is there any reason why the "find" command would be working one way in-line but not the same way in the executed script? It feels like I'm looking for something that's right in front of my nose. Some outside perspective would be greatly appreciated.

Note: Both the source and target systems have versions of Bash 4 (4.4 and 4.3 respectively), so associate arrays should be allowed.

Comment: `-name "'$key'"` likely does not do what you want.  Try `-name "$key"` instead.  Separately, your question will likely get more interest if you (a) provide enough information to make it reproducible, and (b) run some tests and identify which part of the code doesn't do what you want and focus the question down to just that part.

Comment: @John1024 Thanks! Removing the single quotes from the associative array keys as well as "$key" is what worked for me! I wasn't sure how much context was necessary to describe the problem enough to abstract it, I'll strip it down more next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the fundamental misunderstanding is between a shell command string and a program invocation.

A shell command string like this:

```
find . -type d -name 'Other Content'
```

will be turned into an argument list and passed to `find` like this:

`find`, `.`, `-type`, `d`, `-name`, `Other Content`

It's this argument list that decides what `find` does. This is the source of truth. Any command string that results in this argument list will run `find` the way you want. Any command string that results in a different argument list will do something else. Therefore, it's constructing this argument list that you should strive towards.

There's little value in trying to get `echo` to print a shell command string, just like you wouldn't try to write JS or Python by working to have `console.log(..)` or `print(..)` show the statements you want to run.

To more accurately get a sense of resulting arguments, you can use `printf`:

```
$ printf 'Argument: <%s>\n' find . -type d -name 'Other Content'
Argument: <find>
Argument: <.>
Argument: <-type>
Argument: <d>
Argument: <-name>
Argument: <Other Content>
```

If you want to get the same result with contents from a variable, you should make sure the command prints the same thing. In your case, it's not:

```
$ printf 'Argument: <%s>\n' find . -type d -name "'$key'"
Argument: <find>
Argument: <.>
Argument: <-type>
Argument: <d>
Argument: <-name>
Argument: <'Other Content'>  # Different argument, so different result
```

The same technique obviously also demonstrate how your other attempt failed:

```
$ key="'Other Content'"
$ printf 'Argument: <%s>\n' ... -name $key
Argument: <...>
Argument: <-name>
Argument: <'Other>      # Both extra apostrophes
Argument: <Content'>    # and bad splitting
```

When the two `printf` statements produce the same argument list (simply by using `"$key"` in your case), you can remove the `printf '..'` bit and run your `find` command directly.

Comment: Very good analysis.  +1.  It might be worth mentioning that the cause of some of the unanticipated behaviors here are the result of the shell expansions called  _word splitting_ and _quote removal_ which are documented in `man bash`.

Comment: If John1024's comment hadn't have answered my question precisely, this would be a clear way to compare executions of my script and figure out the error. I'll be using this from now on. Thanks for sharing!